# probability/counting problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is an even question from the textbook so unfortunately there's no solution. Suppose $\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}   S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ with $\P({s}) = 1/8$.

Part C) asks *How many events A are there such that P(A) = 1/2?*. Would the answer to this be $8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5$ since there are 4 spots you can "fill" to make the probability 1/2 and since numbers can't repeat?

Comment: Here's a hint that will help you determine if you're on the right track. Start writing out all the events that correspond to the meaning of the formula you proposed,  so 8 possibilities for the first, and then for each of those 8 possibilities, you have 7 possibilities for the second, etc. Check to see if you're double counting anything, and if so, why.

Comment: You need a subset of size four from a sample space of size eight. The event $\{1,2,4,5\}$ is the same as $\{5,2,1,4\}.$ That is, order of listing is unimportant. Also, as you say, no element should be listed more than once. Formula is ${8 \choose 4} = \frac{8!}{4!\cdot 4!}= 70.$ // Try to write all ${8\choose 2} = 28$ possible 2-element events.

Comment: There is no definition of event $A$. So this question has no answer.

Comment: @user158565 You might have misread the question: it characterizes a set of events; it does not attempt to specify a particular event.

Comment: Please add the tag [tag_self-study].